# Using MATLAB for median, quartil, interquartil span and resolution

Tags: matlab, math

I have a picture in MATLAB and decompositioned it to R, G and B channel.
And now I need to figure out *resolution*, *median*, *upper* *and* *lower* *quartil*, *interquartil* *span* and *modus*.

Here is the code I use for it:
close all; clc; clear all

```
I = imread('image_S006_I0000.jpg'); 
 imshow(I)                           


[R S T] = size(I);                  

Red(:,:,1)=I(:,:,1);
Red(:,:,2)=zeros(R,S);
Red(:,:,3)=zeros(R,S);

Green(:,:,1)=zeros(R,S);
Green(:,:,2)=I(:,:,1);
Green(:,:,3)=zeros(R,S);

Blue(:,:,1)=zeros(R,S);
Blue(:,:,2)=zeros(R,S);
Blue(:,:,3)=I(:,:,1);


OR

Red=double(I(:,:,1));
Red=zeros(R,S);
Red=zeros(R,S);

Green=zeros(R,S);
Green=double(I(:,:,1));
Green=zeros(R,S);

Blue=zeros(R,S);
Blue=zeros(R,S);
Blue=double(I(:,:,1));

OR
Red(:,:,1)=double(I(:,:,1));
Green(:,:,1)=double(I(:,:,1));
Blue(:,:,1)=double(I(:,:,1));


cat(3, uint8(Red), zeros(R, S), zeros(R, S));
others = zeros(R, S);
red_plt = cat(3, uint8(Red), others, others);
green_plt = cat(3, others, uint8(Green), others);
blue_plt = cat(3, others, others, uint8(Blue));

figure()
subplot(131);imshow(red_plt)
subplot(132);imshow(green_plt)
subplot(133);imshow(blue_plt)

NOW PLOTTITG (It doesn't print it in Red, Green and Blue color. First two 
are just all black, the third one is black and white):
figure()
subplot(131);imshow(uint8(Red))
subplot(132);imshow(uint8(Green))
subplot(133);imshow(uint8(Blue))


[x1 y1 z1] = size(I);   

% MEDIAN. 
imgmedianR = median (Red(:))
imgmedianG = median (Green(:))
imgmedianB = median (Blue(:))


%QUARTIL
r025 = quantile(Red,0.25) 
r075 = quantile(Red,0.75) 

g025 = quantile(Green,0.25) 
g075 = quantile(Green,0.75) 

b025 = quantile(Blue,0.25) 
b075 = quantile(Blue,0.75) 


%INTERQUARTIL SPAN
r_iqr = iqr(Red) 
g_iqr = iqr(Green) 
b_iqr = iqr(Blue) 


modus_Red = mode(Red(:))
modus_Green = mode(Green(:))
modus_Blue = mode(Blue(:))
```

MEDIAN: When I try to count MEDIAN, it gives me a bunch of numbers (actually matlab prints out a number for each column separately). 
What have I done wrong there?

QUARTIL: The same problem as I have in code for MEDIAN. What have I done wrong there?

INTERQUARTIL SPAN: Matlab prints out subsequent error: 
*Mixed integer class inputs are not supported.*
What have I done wrong?

RESOLUTION: I need to find out a resolution of the image using Matlab. I have tried out funciton *imfinfo*, but the info isn't included. How can I find such an information using any kind of Matlab function?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save every separate colour in a 3d matrix. This is not nessecary. So save them in a 2d matrix as follows:

```
Red=double(I(:,:,1));

Green=double(I(:,:,2));

Blue=double(I(:,:,3));
```

Note there is a conversion to `double`. That's needed for the `iqr`. Also use in every function `Red(:)` instead of `Red` (same for other colours of course). If you change all that, it should work just fine.

Concerning the resolution, that is just the number of pixels for the height and the width, in your case `R` and `S`.

ps you're calling `size(I)` twice.

---

In case of plotting the red, green and blue separately, you need to make the same matrix as the original, with exception that only 1 colour is non-zero. The image is a RxSx3 matrix. So if you want to plot the red part you need to make an RxSx3 matrix where only red is non-zero:

```
cat(3, uint8(Red), zeros(R, S), zeros(R, S));
```

So in total it should look like this

```
others = zeros(R, S);
red_plt = cat(3, uint8(Red), others, others);
green_plt = cat(3, others, uint8(Green), others);
blue_plt = cat(3, others, others, uint8(Blue));

figure()
subplot(131);imshow(red_plt)
subplot(132);imshow(green_plt)
subplot(133);imshow(blue_plt)
```

---

EDIT:

The whole code:

```
I = imread('image_S006_I0000.jpg'); 
 imshow(I)                           

[R S T] = size(I);                  

Red=double(I(:,:,1));

Green=double(I(:,:,2));

Blue=double(I(:,:,3));

others = zeros(R, S);
red_plt = cat(3, uint8(Red), others, others);
green_plt = cat(3, others, uint8(Green), others);
blue_plt = cat(3, others, others, uint8(Blue));

figure()
subplot(131);imshow(red_plt)
subplot(132);imshow(green_plt)
subplot(133);imshow(blue_plt)


% MEDIAN. 
imgmedianR = median (Red(:))
imgmedianG = median (Green(:))
imgmedianB = median (Blue(:))


%QUARTIL
r025 = quantile(Red(:),0.25) 
r075 = quantile(Red(:),0.75) 

g025 = quantile(Green(:),0.25) 
g075 = quantile(Green(:),0.75) 

b025 = quantile(Blue(:),0.25) 
b075 = quantile(Blue(:),0.75) 


%INTERQUARTIL SPAN
r_iqr = iqr(Red(:)) 
g_iqr = iqr(Green(:)) 
b_iqr = iqr(Blue(:)) 


modus_Red = mode(Red(:))
modus_Green = mode(Green(:))
modus_Blue = mode(Blue(:))
```

Comment: I have adjusted the code as following:

     Red(:,:,1)=double(I(:,:,1));
     Red(:,:,2)=zeros(R,S);
     Red(:,:,3)=zeros(R,S);

     Green(:,:,1)=zeros(R,S);
     Green(:,:,2)=double(I(:,:,1));
     Green(:,:,3)=zeros(R,S);

     Blue(:,:,1)=zeros(R,S);
     Blue(:,:,2)=zeros(R,S);
     Blue(:,:,3)=double(I(:,:,1));

Yes, I have just added DOUBLE. 
I can't do such as:

    Red=double(I(:,:,1));
    Red=zeros(R,S);
    Red=zeros(R,S);

Because then I do not plot the figure of RED, BLUE and GREEN correctly (it's all black), it is supposed to be Red, Blue and Green.

Comment: @Franta In the current code, you don't plot anything, so I don't know what you mean. Can you edit your post to include what you mean with plot?

Comment: please see the edit of my original post.
Is it what you meant? 
If yes, it correctly plots only Red. I get subsequent error:

**Multi-plane image inputs must be RGB images of size MxNx3.**

Comment: @Franta your `Red`, `Green` and `blue` are still wrong. I posted the whole code.